# Fix $v \in \mathbb R^n$, the probability matrix $A$ with normally distributed entries has an eigenbasis that $v$ projects nontrivially is $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, random-matrices

Suppose $v \in \mathbb R^n$ is a fixed nonzero vector and $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ is a random matrix where each entry is taken from a standard normal distribution over $\mathbb R$. We know that the probability $A$ is diagonalizable is $1$. My question is: if we concern those matrices that are diagonalizable (thus with an eigenbasis), what is the probability that those with an eigenbasis and $v$ projects nontrivially on each eigenvector in the eigenbasis, i.e., the probability measure of the set
\begin{align*}
\{A \in M_n(\mathbb R): & \text{each entry is generated from a standard normal,}\\
& \text{if $A=S\Lambda S^{-1}$ (spectral decomposition) then $Sv$ has no zero component}\}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Unless $v=0$, the probability that $v$ is is in any proper subspace defined by $A$, is zero. Use this for the finitely many orthogonal complements of the eigenspaces of $A$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Thanks for your comment. But I could not understand what you mean by "proper subspace defined by $A$"? Do you mean the eigenspaces of $A$? I cannot see how this can be argued. Could you point me a reference?

Comment: The probability that $A$ can be diagonalized over $\mathbb{R}$ tends to $0$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$.